# How to let popup.html get focus?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I happen to see that when I update the tabs and set focus to that tab, then the popup is automatically closed. I want the popup to remain open until the user chooses to close it.

What should I do to make this happen?

One more general question is "is it possible for the extensions to open up its popup.html automatically?"

Answer (score 1):

The popup from the browser or pageActions will be displayed only by user clicks and closed when losing focus.

May you consider set focus to the updated tab after your popup is closed or use a classic popup(another window).